# Issue Faced while appending the new child DOM into parent in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to append the N number of 'intentSection' by onClick and getting added only string instead of DOM).

It directly appends the following as string instead of DOM.

```html
<div className="intent">..</div>
```

Here's my code:

```js
let intentSection = '<div className="intent">..</div>';
let reactfindDomNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(intentContainer);
$(reactfindDomNode).append(intentSection);
```

Comment: Try `let intentSection = $('<div className="intent">..</div>');`

Answer (score 2):

While the answer in the comment would probably work, manipulating the actual DOM is an anti-pattern and usually a bad idea. What you should be doing is utilizing the virtual DOM.
 
It isn't clear what you are trying to do here, but I guess it can be done by using the state to determine whether a component should be rendered inside the `render` method `return`